# Unknown "keyhole gallery icon" sometimes appears on lock screen?

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, notification-icons, samsung-galaxy-s-10

Sometimes on my lock screen, an icon with what looks like a keyhole and some sort of gallery-related image appears for a few seconds and then disappears. It happens randomly when I turn on the screen on my phone. It shows among the other notification icons in the middle of the lock screen, and it always disappears by itself after a few seconds even if I don't unlock the phone.

[image: Samsung keyhole gallery icon]

The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S10.

I can't find any settings or apps that seem related or that have this icon, and I can't find the icon when Googling either.

Answer (score 2):

The mystery is solved - apparently it has something to do with the "dynamic wallpaper" feature.

I'll leave this answer here in case someone else sonders about this icon.